# Find out value range of integer types without constants from limits.h

Tags: c

How could I check the maximum value of `signed short int` without using `limits.h`?

Using loops is not efficient I think. Is it possible to make it faster than with loops?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `limits.h`?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid `limits.h`? Using loops isn't possible anyway because it's UB as soon as it overflows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the maximum size of a signed integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843737/calculating-the-maximum-size-of-a-signed-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
int max_short = ((unsigned short)(-1))>>1;
printf("%d\n", max_short);
```

ie the maximum value an unsigned short can assume, shifted over one bit for the sign bit.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `sizeof` to get the size in bytes. from there it's a simple calculation.

any way, why to avoid `limits.h`?

Comment: If your platform has 16-bit chars and short is also 16-bit, `sizeof(short)` will return `1`. The simple calculation you speak of requires multiplication with `CHAR_BIT`, and guess what header that is defined in!

Answer (score 1):

Since you say *check* I assume you want to determine if a given value is the maximal value of a `signed short` (or an `unsigned short`). You can easily check this without including `limits.h` by testing if an overflow occurs: `((X)(x + 1) < x)` will evaluate to true if and only if `x` is the maximal value of its data type `X` (which could be `signed short` for example). The explicit cast is necessary due to integer promotion rules.

Note that this is technically UB as the standard specification does not define signed overflow.